# Creating a Full Fledge Public Website With Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, public-website

I have a website running on Wordpress with slides and would like to implement such in Sharepoint Online (Office 365) because of security issues with wordpress websites.

Please do you think this is something that is feasible and how do you think I can go about it?

If there are videos or materials I need, I dont mind you pointing me in the right directiom.

Please note that the SharePoint I have is the Office365 version and not the on-premises version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has confirmed that they are dropping public website feature from SharePoint online so SharePoint won't be an option.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3027254 and

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3027254/information-about-changes-to-the-sharepoint-online-public-website-feature-in-office-365

Updated answer based on the feedback from @Danny

Comment: You won't have to feel reluctant.. the feature was disabled a year ago. Only users who already created a public site get a grace period till 2017